# AngularJS factory/filter not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory that's keeping track of my translations. Basically I'm setting the language as a string, and then want to update my view using a filter, when the language is changed.

So far if I define the language in my view beforehand, everything is working as expected, but when I click the button to update the language nothing happens.

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

my view:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p >{{ data.title | translate }}</p>
    <p >{{ data.text }}</p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">English</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changeLanguage('sl')">Slovene</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

my script:

```
angular.module('langService', [])
  .factory('Language', function() {
  var currentLanguage = 'en';

  return {
    setCurrentLanguage: function(value) {
      currentLanguage = value;
    },
    getCurrentLanguage: function() {
      return currentLanguage;
    }
  }
});

var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['langService']);

testApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, Language) {
  $scope.data = {
    title: 'PAGE_TITLE',
    text :'some random page text'
  };

  $scope.changeLanguage = function(value) {
    Language.setCurrentLanguage(value);
  }
});

testApp.constant('Translations', {
  en: {
    'PAGE_TITLE': 'Hi!'
  },
  sl: {
    'PAGE_TITLE': 'Živjo!'
  }
});

testApp.filter('translate', function(Translations, Language) {
  return function(input) {
    return Translations[Language.getCurrentLanguage()][input] || '';
  };
});
```

I've created this as an example in [codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/PZpgzv) to try it out before implementing it in a project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think because your data did not change, the expression is not being re-evaluated. Does a explicit $scope.$digest() help at the end of the changeLanguage method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good practice to have a stateful filter, but in your case it's a valid use case - needs to be re-evaluated (on digest loop). So your filter needs to be "marked" that it's stateful.

```
testApp.filter('translate', function(Translations, Language) {

  function translateFilter(input) {
    return Translations[Language.getCurrentLanguage()][input] || '';
  };

  // marked as stateful
  translateFilter.$stateful = true;

  return translateFilter;

});
```

Search for "stateful" filter in docs for more information:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Btw for translations you can use angular-translate. http://angular-translate.github.io/ See their filter implementation https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/src/filter/translate.js